# Display image with type byte[] after return as JSON in html element

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am getting data from database table which has column with type varbinary(max).

I saved my image in the table successfully and even after getting data everything was working well, but after returning data to the Html with return Json(data) nothing were displayed just some binary codes. I don't have any idea about how to view the binary image like an image not just some binary codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add image tag with id or class in your HTML

```
<img id="myimage" src="" />
```

Add script to call API and display byte[] to image src.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: '/api/image/getimage',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#myimage').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + data);
            },
            error: function (error) {

            }
        });
});
```

Note: `data:image/png;base64` or `data:image/jpg;base64` base on your image type.

Comment: I didin,t want to show image in image tag but I wanted to display data in a grid any way it worked for me perfectly